# How to start activities from this RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-recyclerview

i have a RecyclerView full of elements which in this case are CardViews,i also have a switch that depending on the status sorts the elements of the RecyclerView so depending on this the elements change their position, i want to go to a different activity from each one of the elements of the recycler view, but i'm kinda stuck since i haven't found any source that initialize the data of the elemets the way i did.

HERE IS THE RECYCLERVIEW:

```
public class CategoriesRecyclerView extends Activity {
    private List<Categories> categories;
    private RecyclerView rv;
    private Switch categoriesSortingSwitch;
    private TextView switchStatus;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.categories_recycler_view);


        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cardList);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

        initializeData();

        final CategoriesAdapter ca = new CategoriesAdapter(categories);
        rv.setAdapter(ca);



        //IMPLEMENTACIÓN DE EL SORTING POR MEDIO DE EL SWITCH
        categoriesSortingSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchsortcategories);
        switchStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testswitch);
        //set the switch to OFF
        categoriesSortingSwitch.setChecked(false);
        //attach a listener to check for changes in state
        categoriesSortingSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if(isChecked){
                    switchStatus.setText("Sorting alphabetically");


                    Collections.sort(categories, new Comparator<Categories>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(Categories lhs, Categories rhs) {
                            return lhs.title.compareTo(rhs.title);
                        }
                    });


                    ca.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }else{
                    switchStatus.setText("Sorting by popularity");

                    Collections.sort(categories, new Comparator<Categories>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(Categories rhs, Categories lhs) {
                            return lhs.title.compareTo(rhs.title);
                        }
                    });

                ca.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }
        });


        //check the current state before we display the screen
        if(categoriesSortingSwitch.isChecked()){
            switchStatus.setText("Sorting alphabetically");


            Collections.sort(categories, new Comparator<Categories>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Categories lhs, Categories rhs) {
                    return lhs.title.compareTo(rhs.title);
                }
            });


        }
        else {
            switchStatus.setText("Sorting by popularity");

            Collections.sort(categories, new Comparator<Categories>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Categories rhs, Categories lhs) {
                    return lhs.title.compareTo(rhs.title);
                }
            });

        }

    }

    private void initializeData() {


        categories = new ArrayList<>();
        categories.add(new Categories("CARS", "CARS"));
        categories.add(new Categories("SPORTS", "SPORTS"));
        categories.add(new Categories("GAMING", "GAMING"));
        categories.add(new Categories("GAMBLING", "GAMBLING"));
        categories.add(new Categories("TECH", "TECH"));
        categories.add(new Categories("NATURE", "NATURE"));
        categories.add(new Categories("RANDOM", "RANDOM"));
        categories.add(new Categories("COUSINE", "COUSINE"));
        categories.add(new Categories("HISTORY", "HISTORY"));
        categories.add(new Categories("MUSIC", "MUSIC"));
        categories.add(new Categories("STUDIES", "STUDIES"));
    }

}
```

AND HERE IS THE ADAPTER:

```
public class CategoriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoriesAdapter.CategoriesViewHolder>  {

    private List<Categories> categoriesList;

    public CategoriesAdapter(List<Categories> categoriesList) {
        this.categoriesList = categoriesList;

    }


    public static class CategoriesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CardView cv;
        TextView title;
        TextView category_title;

        //ImageView category_img; CUANDO VALLA A REMPLAZAR LA FORO DE CATEGORIA

        CategoriesViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            category_title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_title);
            //category_img = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_picture);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categoriesList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CategoriesViewHolder categoriesViewHolder, final int i) {
        Categories ci = categoriesList.get(i);

        categoriesViewHolder.title.setText(categoriesList.get(i).title);
        categoriesViewHolder.category_title.setText(categoriesList.get(i).category_title);
        //categoriesViewHolder.categori_img.setImageResource(categoriesList.get(i).photoId);
    }

    @Override
    public CategoriesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.category_row, viewGroup, false);

        return new CategoriesViewHolder(itemView);
    }
}
```

I will really appreciate any instruction on how to do this.
Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your ViewHolder to implement View.OnClickListener. In the onClick() method you can call ViewHolder.getAdapterPosition() and check which activity should be launched by the item in that position.

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();

        // Logic to start correct activity class based on position
    }
}
```

Doing it this way ensures that you only create new listeners on ViewHolder creation. If you create new listeners in onBindView(), you'll be creating new objects every time you scroll.

Another option is to use different View types. Set your adapter to return a different integer in getItemViewType() depending on what behavior you want in onClick. Then, in onCreateViewHolder(), you can add an OnClickListener and use that integer (passed as the viewType parameter) to determine its behavior. However, if all of your list items are launching different activities, then this will mean you need a separate View type for each item, and then they won't be recycled very efficiently.

Comment: Had to made some changes on my code in order to use context to initialize the new activity, it is working now, thank you so much.

Comment: @Sebastian, You can grab a context inside the ViewHolder by calling itemView.getContext(), and shouldn't need to change much else.

Answer (score 2):

To start new Activity from `RecyclerView` item click set ,onClick listener for root View of row in `onCreateViewHolder`:

```
@Override
  public CategoriesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup,int i){
         View itemView =....;
         itemView.setClickable(true);
         itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
          {
           @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
              // starte new Activity here
            }
         });
        return new CategoriesViewHolder(itemView);
    }
```

And also if child views in `category_row` layout if focusable then set `android:duplicateParentState="true"` for each view.

Comment: but how do i make it lauch a different activity for each elemnt of the RecyclerView ? thanks in advance.

Comment: @SebastianDelgado: then add switch-case inside `onClick` method for starting different Activities according to row click

Answer (score 0):

Do it in onBindViewHolder.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CategoriesViewHolder categoriesViewHolder, final int i) {
    final Categories ci = categoriesList.get(i);

    categoriesViewHolder.title.setText(categoriesList.get(i).title);
    categoriesViewHolder.category_title.setText(categoriesList.get(i).category_title);
    //categoriesViewHolder.categori_img.setImageResource(categoriesList.get(i).photoId);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // launch activity by Categories

        }
    });
}
```